# How to disable some cores on Intel machine

Tags: linux, motherboard, multi-core, xeon, processor-socket

I have a machine with two Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2618L v3 processor, which has 8 cores on each socket.

I only want the OS or hypervisor (such as Xen) on the machine to detect only one socket and only 4 cores.

**My questions are:**

1) Is there (software) anyway that I can disable one socket and make it invisible to the OS running directly on it?

2) Is there anyway that I can disable part of the cores and make them invisible to the OS running on it?

**Below is what I tried:**

1) I knew that I can dissemble the machine and physically remove a socket from the motherboard, but this is too "bloody" to me and I'm afraid it may break the socket which I may want to use later.

2) I checked the BIOS configuration and there is no option that I can disable part of the cores or disable a socket.

3) I know that Xen provide the boot command line to configure a VM to only use part of the cores. This is just a walk-around approach. What if I want Xen only aware of 4 cores, instead of 8 cores? What if I have to run OS on the machine without virtualization?

**Why do I want to do this?**

I'm doing some research on the OS and hypervisor, which assumes that there are only 4 cores  and one socket. I want to tune the hardware to follow the assumption so that the system can run. Right now, the customized OS and customized Xen can only run on one socket with 4 cores. :-(

I knew that the best practice is to improve the customized OS and customized Xen to make it capable on more flexible hardware. But it may need more time and I'm curious about the hardware-side solution. :-)

Thank you very much for your time and help in this question!

Comment: Windows lets you you indicate how many votes it should see, virtualization software also let you setup a virtual machine with only specific number of cores, which one don't you know who to do?  Why would you physically remove the socket, that makes no sense, just removing the CPU would make more sense rather then breaking your socket by removing it....

Comment: Oh, I'm using Linux or Xen. So windows is not an option here, unfortuanately. In addition, the system I'm using is a customized Xen hypervisor, which only runs on 4 core machine. :-( the Linux I'm using is a Linux with customized scheduler which only runs on 4 core machine. So I want the priviledged software, such as Linux and Xen, totoally unaware of the existance of the  cores so that the customized systems can run smoothly... :-(

Comment: I should have clarified.  Operating systems in general let you decide how many cores it can see.  I cannot think of a single virtualization software that does not let you configure how many cores the VM will have.

Comment: @Ramhound, actually, my question is how to make the hypervisor only aware of 4 cores instead of 8 cores. I know how to configure a VM with a specific number of CPUs; But I want the hypervisor aware of only 4 cpus instead of 8 cpus.

Comment: I know VirtualBox, Hyper-V, and VMWare all provide you the ability to choose how many CPUs and how many cores each of those CPUs will be visiable to the virtual machine.  Does Xen not provide that option?

Comment: @Ramhound Xen provide this option to make a part of cores avaialbe to VMs. But Xen kernel still see the full number of cores... :-(